# Vue-i18n and v-select - can't translate

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-i18n

I have a problem to translate the information with vue i18n in my v-select. All others translation work but not this one... And i don't find a solution ...

HTML :

```
<v-card-text>
    <v-select v-model="model" :items="propsList" :items-text="propsList.text" label="Select a reason:" clearable />
</v-card-text>
```

DATA eg : ($t = i18n)

```
propsList: [
    { text: this.$t('XXX.A') as string, value: 'X' },
    { text: this.$t('XXX.B') as string, value: 'Y' },
    { text: this.$t('XXX.C') as string, value: 'Z' },
],
```

Traduction :

```
{ "en": {
    "XXX" : {
        "A": "A", ...}},
  "fr": {
    "XXX" : {
        "A": "A", ...}},
```

In my App.vue :

```
data ... : 

languages: [
    { text: 'English', value: 'en' },
    { text: 'Français', value: 'fr' },
],

watch: {
    language(val: string) {
        this.setLanguage(val);
        this.$i18n.locale = val;
    },
},
```

I'm keep trying ! But thanks by advance :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a prop called :get-option-label that is useful for i18n, that way you can just pass the i18n key in your option array:

```
<v-select :options="options" :get-option-label="option => $t(option.text)"></v-select>
```

Then options would look like this:

```
options = [
  { text: "XXX.A", value: 0 }
  { text: "XXX.B", value: 1 }
  { text: "XXX.C", value: 3 }
]
```

More details: https://vue-select.org/api/props.html#getoptionlabel

Comment: In Vuetify 3, this parameter has been replaced by `item-title`

Answer (score 0):

`v-select` doesn't have a prop named 'items-text' (items with s). You probably mean `item-text` (without s).

the prop `item-text` is used to specify the "path" where each item of your data has the text, it defaults to the string "text" which means the text of the item is found at the property "text"

if for example, you have the item with the structure:

```
{
  value: 'some value',
  name: 'John'
}
```

You should pass the string "name".

since you have your data with the text as `text` property, your template should look like this:

```
<v-card-text>
    <v-select v-model="model" :items="propsList" label="Select a reason:" clearable />
</v-card-text>
```

Other options for this prop are:

- **An array of strings**

  Use this for nested properties, say for example you have your item's structure as follows:

```js
{
 value: 'whatever',
 data: {
   name: {
     en: 'John'
   }
 }
}
```

you should pass `['data', 'name', 'en']`, Vuetify will resolve the name.

- **A callback function**

  The callback function you pass will be called for each item and the item itself will be passed as a parameter, you should return whatever string you want to be displayed, this might be useful if you want to concatenate two properties of your items, e.g. first name and last name. or to display a prefix based on some value

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late for the party but this might help someone who bumped on this issue recently.
**TLDR answer**: You can use slots to customize almost everything with v-select and many other like v-data-table. In our case its the `item` slot. The slots for each component are listed in the API, however many EXIST but are NOT documented so you might look around their forum/github for community input.

Detailed answer:

```
<v-select
  :items="cities"
  v-model="city"
  item-text="name"
  item-value="id"
>
<template v-slot:item="{ active, item, attrs, on }">
  <v-list-item v-on="on" v-bind="attrs" #default="{ active }">
    <v-list-item-content>
      <v-list-item-title>
        <v-row no-gutters align="center" class="ml-3">
          <span>{{ $t(item.name) }}</span>
        </v-row>
      </v-list-item-title>
    </v-list-item-content>
  </v-list-item>
</template>
<template v-slot:selection="{ active, item, attrs, on }">
  <div v-on="on" v-bind="attrs">
    {{ $t(item.name) }}

  </div>
</template>
</v-select>
```

So how does this code solve the problem?

1)item-text and item-value -> we take an object that has props name and id, we use the ID as return value and the name as the display text in our dropdown

2)within the v-select tag we define with  the custom behavior and we accept "active" as state of the menu, "item" - exactly what we need to pass to the i18n tranlsator or ANY OTHER piece of logic, "on" which is the event trigger, and the "attrs" - attributes which are the props of the v-select object(black magic happening here)

3)we style as we want the list-item and in my case the name is passed to a translator function that resides in the global app scope.

4)we manipulate the selection slot to translate not only the dropdown menu items but also the selected value. In this case since we don't need the "active" prop we can use a plain div and add any markup we want. In this case we don't need a v-list item because it adds side margins, but you can customize as you wish.

You can append icons, inject components and many more things. Pretty powerful.